# ! LaTeX Error: File `algorithm2e.sty' not found

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using Centos 7.8 and installed texlive using

```
yum install texlive*
```

I tried installing using `yum install texlive-full` but it did not find any package named like this.

It turns out I can not use algpseudocode, algorithm2e by installing like this. How can I install them manually or how can I install texlive-full (if it can make any difference) on Centos 7. On my ubuntu machine it works perfect.

Also I have tried to install `yum install texlive-science` but it did not find any package named like this.

Comment: Centos 7 is pretty old and I'm suspecting its TeXlive packages are as well. Have you considered uninstalling the rpm packages and install TeXlive directly from TUG using the [install-tl](https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) script? You'll get tlmgr and can install or uninstall any package individually.

Comment: I have not tried that, I'll try and post the update here